# How can parse string to time with milliseconds in Lumen?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

Use case: the client send the time parsed as string in a Json ('mm:ss:ffff') to database. Before the difference can be calculated on API. The string must be parsed back at time.

I tried this:

```
$timeA = Carbon::createFromFormat('mm:ss:SSSS',($user->timeA));
$timeB = Carbon::createFromFormat('mm:ss:SSSS',($user->timeB));

$result = $timeB->diff($timeA);
```

Postman says: "Unexpected data found. Data missing"

Comment: Check out the formats for createFromFormat!
Try 'H:i:u' .

Comment: I have the formats from this Site >> https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ ... maybe is this a "problem" >> i need only minutes:seconds:milliseconds << I try to find later a solution.  thx for help @jspit

Comment: Format's for isoformat are not equal format's for createfromformat. See examles. Use format '!i:s:u' for createFromFormat (not H:i:u)

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot @jspit I've learned something again!

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this issue by using parse function :

```
$timeA = Carbon::parse(($user->timeA));
$timeB = Carbon::parse(($user->timeB));

$result = $timeB->diff($timeA);
```

Comment: Also I tried this and Postman says: "Could not parse '37:17:7805': DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (37:17:7805) at position 0 (3): Unexpected character"    thx for try to help.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

Thanks to @jspit!

My solution for calculate the difference between 2 times with format from string to time and the result back to string with Carbon.

```
  private function timeDiff(String $timeA, String $timeB)
    {
        $time1 = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s.u',($timeA));
        $time2 = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s.u',($timeB));
        $difference = $time2->diff($time1);
        return $difference->format('%H:%i:%s.%f');
    }
```